# Read specific data from a text file and calculate a result

Tags: matlab, time, text-files

I have to read data from a text file:

How do I find the total time the machine was **ON** for?
I could get the individual times when the machine is on but I can't seem to figure out how to add it to get the total **on** time.

Note: Simply adding it won't give the answer. The total on time should be 31.

Comment: you should start a script and tell us where it broke. I recommend reading the data with readable, then checking the diff(table.time) to get lengths of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Building a State Graph Using Timestamps by Interpolation

---

### Output Results:

[image: Results]

---

### Reading in the Data:

This question has two key parts reading the data and evaluating the data. The `textscan()` function can be used to read the data with format specification `%d %f %s`. This indicates that column 1 should be read/scanned in as an integer, `%d`, column 2 as a float, `%f` and column 3 as a string, `%s`. All this data is scanned into a cell array called `Data` in this example.
[image: Data Array Results]

---

### Analyzing the Data:

After separating the columns of `Data` into respective arrays the rows corresponding to "on" times can be evaluated. Here the `contains()` function is used to evaluate the rows in the `Status` array/column appear as "on". The `contains()` function returns true "1" when the second argument is found in the array and returns "0" otherwise for each element in the first argument. The next step is to use matrix-indexing to index the `Time` array to grab the corresponding durations where the `Status` is "on". From here interpolation can be employed to build a state graph where "1" represents "ON" and "0" represents "OFF". Using the `interp1()` function allows the signal to be interpolated for a new set of points/axis. In this case, we need to interpolate all the states between the timestamps. Using the previous interpolation method allows the desired effect to be achieved. After getting the graph the sum of `Interpolated_Binary_State` can be taken to get the duration based on the timestamps in the text file.
[image: ON/OFF State Graph]

---

### Full Script:

```
clear;
clc;

%Reading in the data as a cell array%
fileID = fopen('Text.txt', 'r');

Header = string(fgetl(fileID));
Data = textscan(fileID,'%d %f %s');

fclose(fileID);

%Splitting the data into specific columns%
Time = Data(:,1);
Time = Time{1,1};
Power = Data(:,2); 
Power = Power{1,1};
Status = Data(:,3);
Status = string(Status{1,1});

%Binary state graph%
Binary_State = contains(Status,"on");

%Interpolating the binary state graph for every interval between the
%timestamps%
Interpolated_Time = (0:max(Time));
Interpolated_Binary_State = interp1(double(Time),double(Binary_State),double(Interpolated_Time),'previous');

%Plotting the state graph%
stairs(Interpolated_Time,Interpolated_Binary_State);
title("State Graph ON (1) and OFF (0)");
xlabel("Time"); ylabel("State (ON/OFF)");
ylim([0 1.1]);
xticks(0:max(Time));

Total_On_Time = sum(Interpolated_Binary_State)
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Yes, I did separate the data like this but simply adding the time like this won't give the total time as those are 'time stamps'. It only shows when power has changed. Adding all those will give an error. The total on time should be 31.

Comment: @skycharm My bad though those were durations. I'll add the way to build a state graph through interpolation and add the time under the state graph based on the timestamps.

Comment: yes that worked! Could you please explain how 'previous' works in the interp1 function

Comment: @skycharm `previous` indicates that when MATLAB is attempting to interpolate the values in between it should use the known left neighbouring value. In this case it will continue to extend the `ON` or `OFF` state until a known timestamp is hit. To see the difference between interpolation modes trying `linear` and `nearest ` may give some insight.

Comment: @skycharm Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the green checkmark if this has sufficiently answered your question.